# How to import and use typescript interface stored in a auto generated *.d.ts file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

In a React Application, I have got this structure:

```
src/Components/MyComponent

├── MyComponent.module.css // Css modules styles
├── MyComponent.module.css.d.ts // Autogenerated style type definition
└── MyComponent.tsx // The React component
```

`Component.module.css.d.ts` contains this:

```
interface CssExports {
  'myCssClass01': string;
  'myCssClass02': string;
}
declare const cssExports: CssExports;
export = cssExports;
```

In `MyComponent.tsx` I want to import the `interface` and use it in a function, like this:

```
import styles from './MyComponent.module.css'
import { cssExports } from './MyComponent.module.css.d'

const myFunc = (style: cssExports): string => {...}
```

I am receiving error:

> Module '"/src/components/MyComponent/MyComponent.module.css"' has no exported member 'cssExports'.ts(2305)

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using commonjs module syntax, Can you enable this flag in tsconfig.json and try again

```
"esModuleInterop": true
```

Also export interface as well like below

*// MyComponent.module.css*

```
export interface CssExports {
  'myCssClass01': string;
  'myCssClass02': string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `esModuleInterop` is already `true`.
`MyComponent.module.css.d.ts` is generated by `css-modules-typescript-loader`. If I could edit it adding an export directly on the interface instead of the default export I probably could solve importing the interface in this way:
`import styles, { cssExports } from './MyComponent.module.css'`
But I can't.. :-(